# Google Chart API - How to access chart components at a specific position in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, google-visualization

Usually you have event handler which catch mouse move or click events and give access to the element laying under mouse (a series or a cell) and a position (x, y). But in my case I have a screen point (x, y) need to access chart element it is targeting (if there is any).

In traditional way (Windows forms) there is a method like this ElementAt(int x, int y) in chart class and return value is an object like label, series, point, marker, ... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Visualization API does not expose any method to get the element(s) at a given set of coordinates.

Some of the charts support the ChartLayoutInterface, which allows you to get some information about the chart elements.  You can use the CLI's `#getBoundingBox` method to get the top and left edges (relative to the chart container) and height and width of a given chart element.  If you parse over all of the chart elements, you can get positions for all of them, so when you need to compare screen coordinates to elements, you could find the elements at the coordinates.

Unfortunately, there is no good way to get a list of all of the chart elements, so you would basically have to write functions that iterate over all possible elements in each element type until you fail to find one.